# An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am getting the following error on the query copied below:

> An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Since there is no 1 to 1 join on d.VCMN and h.VDMN, I want to join on d.VCMN <= max(h.VDMN) for that h.P_ID, b.S_U_ID

How do I set up a SQL for this situation?

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.P_ID
    ,B.S_U_ID
    ,H.vdmn
    ,D.VCMN AS VCMN _d
    ,C.I_A_ID
    ,D.I_A_V_ID
FROM PSH H
LEFT JOIN PSU B ON h.SH_ID = B.SH_ID
LEFT JOIN PPA C ON b.UA_ID = C.PA_ID
LEFT JOIN PIA_V D ON c.IIA_ID = d.IA_ID
    AND D.VCMN <= max(H.VDMN)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query leaves a lot open to interpretation.  I should add that using `select distinct` with multiple joins is also very suspicious.

Comment: Use a sub.query, i.e.  `... <= (select max(VDMN) FROM ... )`

Comment: when you say max(H.VDMN) - over what groupinf are you wanting to know the MAX?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
From (select h.*, max(vdmn) over (partition by sh_id) as max_vdmn
      from PSH H
     ) h left join
     PSU B
     on h.SH_ID = B.SH_ID left join
     PPA C
     on b.UA_ID = C.PA_ID left join
     PIA_V D
     on c.IIA_ID = d.IA_ID and D.VCMN <= h.max_vdmn
```

The `partition by sh_id` is just a guess on what you might want to accomplish.  It is likely that some `partition by` might solve this particular syntax problem.